# Closing FrameLayout for a Fragment in Android App

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm working on a simple Android App as a self-learning Project. I've got a lot of it functioning, and I have a main `Activity` which has a `FrameLayout` and some `RecyclerView` and `FloatingActionButton` stuff going on inside of it.

However, I want to make one of my buttons in my `NavigationDrawer` open a different view in the FrameLayout using `Fragments`. Is there a way to do this, sort of making a new Fragment for the `RecyclerView` and the other stuff and putting the `RecyclerView` and `FloatingActionButton` in there?

I tried doing something like this (when the appropriate `NavigationDrawer` button was clicked):

```
statsFragment = new StatsFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.rootLayout, statsFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
```

But this caused my app to crash. Any pointers?

Comment: Show us some codes to actually understand what you are doing

Comment: what was the crash ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your **R.id.rootLayout** a `Layout` or a `Fragment` component?

If your main `Activity` has a hard coded `Fragment` (by hard coded i mean declared in your XML), then **no**, you can't change a hard-coded fragment content with `FragmentTransaction`.
More information on [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810348/android-fragment-replace-doesnt-replace-content-puts-it-on-top).

Finally, you can't *put* your components from one `Activity` inside a new `Fragment`/`Activity` since each component belongs to one and **only one** `Context`.
See, `Activity` extends `Context`. When you get a reference to a component declared in your XML by using `Activity.findViewById(int)`, you are actually making a pointer to a determined `View` from this `Activity`'s layout, defined in your `onCreate`method with [setContentView(id)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView(int)). You can't take this pointer and throw it to another `Fragment` or `Activity` within your application without expecting any problems. (Well, maybe you can, but it's totally against the best practices of Android Programming).