# Android - Start Fragemnt from another Fragment C#

Tags: c#, android, android-fragments, xamarin, fragment

I know this question has been asked too much here but i ahve tried every solution out there to open a fragment from another fragment and no one worked for me.

**Fragment1.cs**

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.my_layout, container, false);
    return view;
    add.Click += delegate
        {
            Fragment2 fragment2 = new Fragment2();
            FragmentTransaction ft = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
            ft.Replace(Resource.Id.content_frame, fragment2);
            ft.Commit();
         };
}
```

**my_layout**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/content_frame">
<TextView
    android:text="Text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/total"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="30dp" />
<TextView
    android:text="Text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textchangevalue"
    android:textSize="33dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
<Button
    android:text="UPDATE"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/updatebtn" />
 <Button
    android:text="ADD"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/addbtn" />
 <ListView
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/portfoliolist"
    android:clickable="true" />
```

**Fragment2.cs**

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment_lay, container, false);

        TextView txt = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
        Button btn = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
        listView = view.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView1);
        Toast.MakeText(Activity, "Fragment2 started", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        return view;
       }
```

When I run the app, and click the `add` button nothing is happening. Why is that ? I have tried to change the layout of the `Fragment1` by putting instead of `<LinearLayout>` a `<FrameLayout>` but also disn't worked. Please help me to find a solution.

**EDIT:**
I have put a `toast` message in the `Fragment2` and when I click the `add` button in the `fragment1`, the `toast` message (which is in the `fragment2`) is showing which means that the `fragment2` is starting fine but it's layout is not showing on the screen.

Comment: You are trying to attach a listener after method is returned, which is not going to happen ever.

Comment: Hello, does my answer work for you?

Comment: @JoeLv-MSFT yes it did but would you please tell me how to high-lite `NavuagtionDrawer` item from a Fragment on button click ? Because now when I click the button, it takes me to the secondFragment but the firstfragment is still the highlited one when I swipe the Navigationdrawer menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `FrameLayout` to contain your `LinearLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/content_frame">
  <LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/ll"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:text="Text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:id="@+id/total"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="30dp" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textchangevalue"
        android:textSize="33dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <Button
        android:text="UPDATE"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/updatebtn" />
    <Button
        android:text="ADD"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/addbtn" />
    <ListView
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/portfoliolist"
        android:clickable="true" />
  </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

And your code should be :

```
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // Use this to return your custom view for this Fragment
        var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.my_layout, container, false);
        var ll = view.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.ll);
        var bt = view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.addbtn);
        bt.Click+= delegate
        {
            Fragment2 fragment2 = new Fragment2();
            FragmentTransaction ft = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
            ft.Replace(Resource.Id.content_frame, fragment2);
            ft.Commit();
            ll.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
        };
        return view;
    }
```

You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810348/android-fragment-replace-doesnt-replace-content-puts-it-on-top) to see why your `fragment2` just top on it. I use `ll.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;` to avoid it.

Comment: Would you please check this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50746357/android-check-listview-items-on-the-start-of-the-app)

Comment: I have seen that, but today I am busy, i will do it next week.

Comment: Would you mind to check this thread also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50763580/android-shared-preferences-in-broadcast)

Answer (score 0):

You have to attach your `Click` event to your button **before** `return` the `view`, and I think that you want to attach this event on your `addbtn` so you have to create the variable `add` before to attach this event

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.my_layout, container, false);
    Button add = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.addbtn);
    add.Click += delegate
    {
        Fragment2 fragment2 = new Fragment2();
        FragmentTransaction ft = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        ft.Replace(Resource.Id.content_frame, fragment2);
        ft.Commit();
    };
    return view;
}
```

Comment: No, it didn't worked. I have put the `return view` after the event, nothing changed, still when I click the `add` button nothing is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the events instead:

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.my_layout, container, false);
    Button add = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.addbtn);
    add.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
    {
        Fragment2 fragment2 = new Fragment2();
        FragmentTransaction ft = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        ft.Replace(Resource.Id.content_frame, fragment2);
        ft.Commit();
    };

    return view;
}
```

Comment: I tried it, it is not working. But I have put a toast message in the `Fragment2` and when I click the `add` button in the `fragment1`, the toast message is showing which means that the `fragment2` is starting but not showing.

Comment: @Wassim01 Post the code of your Fragment and XML. If you put the toast in the event, it only means that the event is fired

Comment: I have edited my question, plus, the `toast` is in the fragment2 which means the `add` button event is firing and the fragment2 is launching well but it's layout is not showing on the screen

Comment: @Wassim01 You need to return the view when you finish the onCreate in your fragment

Comment: I did but i forgot to put it in my code above. Sorry. Actually, visualstudio throws an error if you don't put `return view`.

Comment: There are some problems in your fragment_lay XML, or with what are you trying to replace. I suggest you have a look here on how to properly structure your fragments: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Creating-and-Using-Fragments