# Android - Check custom listView items on the start of the App

Tags: c#, android, list, listview, xamarin

I have a custom `Listview`, each row contains one `textview`and one checkbox. I am saving the value (or the text) of the selected row's `textview` in a public list named `usercoin`. Each time the user opens the app, the list `usercoin` will contain the text of the his `textview` selected items, and I am doing that using `SQLite`. The problem is I want to re-check the items which the usaer have previously selected which are available in the `usercoin` list. I am not able to do so.

**MyActivity.cs**

```
    ListView mListView;
    MyAdapter adapter;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        mListView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listview);
        List<TableList> list = new List<TableList>();

        list.Add(new TableList("Germany",false));
        list.Add(new TableList("France", false));
        list.Add(new TableList("Finland", false));
        list.Add(new TableList("Germany", false));
        list.Add(new TableList("France", false));
        list.Add(new TableList("Germany", false));
        list.Add(new TableList("France", false));
        list.Add(new TableList("Finland", false));

        adapter = new MyAdapter(this, list);
        mListView.Adapter = adapter;
        mListView.ItemClick += MListView_ItemClick;
    }

    private void MListView_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var t = list[e.Position];
        string selected = t.name;
        var ll = e.View as LinearLayout;
        var cb = ll.GetChildAt(2) as CheckBox;
        if (cb.Checked)
        {
            cb.Checked = false;
            adapter.changeState((int)cb.Tag, false);
        }
        else
        {
            cb.Checked = true;
            adapter.changeState((int)cb.Tag, true);
        }
    }



    class MyAdapter : BaseAdapter
    {
        Context mContext;
        List<TableList> mitems;
        public MyAdapter(Context context, List<TableList> list)
        {
            this.mContext = context;
            this.mitems = list;

        }
        public override int Count
        {
            get
            {
                return mitems.Count;
            }
        }

        public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
        {
            return mitems[position];
        }

        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }

        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            DataViewHolder holder = null;
            if (convertView == null)
            {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.From(mContext).Inflate(Resource.Layout.CoinList, null, false);
                holder = new DataViewHolder();
                holder.tv = convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.CoinName);
                holder.iv = convertView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);
                holder.cb = convertView.FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.checkBox1);
                convertView.Tag = holder;
            }
            else
            {
                holder = convertView.Tag as DataViewHolder;

            }
            holder.cb.Tag = position;

            holder.tv.Text = mitems[position].Name;
            holder.cb.Focusable = false;
            holder.cb.Checked = mitems[position].bl;
            holder.iv.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.dapao);
            holder.cb.CheckedChange += Cb_CheckedChange;
            return convertView;

        }

        private void Cb_CheckedChange(object sender, CompoundButton.CheckedChangeEventArgs e)
        {
            var cb = sender as CheckBox;
            if (e.IsChecked && !mitems[(int)cb.Tag].bl)
            {
                mitems[(int)cb.Tag].bl = true;
                this.NotifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            else if (!e.IsChecked && mitems[(int)cb.Tag].bl)
            {
                mitems[(int)cb.Tag].bl = false;
                this.NotifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        internal void changeState(int tag, bool v)
        {
            mitems[tag].bl = v;
            this.NotifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    public class DataViewHolder : Java.Lang.Object
    {
        public ImageView iv { get; set; }
        public TextView tv { get; set; }
        public CheckBox cb { get; set; }

    }
    public class TableList : Java.Lang.Object
    {
        private string v;



        public TableList(string name, bool b)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.bl = b;
        }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool bl { get; set; }
    }
}
}
```

For example, when the user run the app and select `France` and `Germany` from the `listview`, next time he opens the app, the `usercoin` list will contain `France` and `Germany`. Now the question is how can I check the checkboxes corresponding to those values in the `listview`. I have tried to do so by including this code in `MyAdapter : BaseAdapter` class:

```
if (Class1.usercoin.Contains(item.CoinAbr))
            {
                Class1.adapter[(int)holder.cb.Tag].bl = true;
                this.NotifyDataSetChanged();
            }
```

But when this code get executed, the previously checked items are checked plus some other items which the user haven't checked previously are also checked. So how can I check the previously checked items in the `Listview` on the app start ? Please help me to find a solution.

Comment: You would store the user's selections in a local store (Sqlite, Realm, a file, etc..) and retrieve them at the application startup.  Example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/data-access/using-sqlite-orm

Comment: I've removed your `visual-studio` tag for you because this isn't a question about the Visual Studio development environment (see the tags wiki)

Comment: @SushiHangover yea I am saving them using `Sqlite` but i didn't showed that in my code, I am asking about retrieving. I am not able to retrieve them on the start of the activity.

Comment: What do you mean by `I am not able to retrieve them on the start of the activity`? I would like to get the data firstly in the [Application](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/2147/what-is-the-recipe-to-have-a-working-application-derived-class), because Application is the first class to run in Android. And you can define your `useritems` in your Application class as Global Variable.

Comment: @JoeLv-MSFT Yes `useritems` is already a gobal list but I didn't put that in my question's code. Here's what i want to do: user checks his item for the first time, let them be germany and France then he quite the app. Then he re-open it, he needs to see his previously checked items (Germany and France) checked automatically in the Listview so he doesn't need to re-check them again.

Comment: Hello, cause you have post your database code, so I did it by myself, you can refer to my demo.

Answer (score 0):

I have stored the data(`useritems`) in both DataBase and memory.

If your app is killed by system or user, you can restore the data from DataBase.

If your app isn't killed by system or user, but user jump to other activity, when he back to this activity, you can use memory to restore the data.

About DataBase, I am use [SQLite.Net](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/data-access/using-sqlite-orm). I am using `DBHelper` to operation the DataBase.

And I have add Application class in the app.

I have update the [demo](https://github.com/xiaolvzi/ListViewCheckBox). [Here](https://github.com/xiaolvzi/ListViewCheckBox/upload) is gif.

Comment: Well, I have tried tour solution, when I first run the app, I am getting no items in my `listview`. Why is that ? Plus, I have already saved usercoin in a `database` so if you could edit your code by assuming it is saved in database and you are only getting it out of it.

Comment: By `when I first run the app, I am getting no items in my listview`, ok, I will test it tomorrow, but I don't understand your question, now.  so, I suggest that, tomorrow, I will debug my demo, and push it, you can compare it with yours. You can ask me any question about my code. Or show your code about the read database, so I can find why you can't get data from database.

Comment: Okay, I ll provide how I am saving usercoin to `database` athough it is not easy to understand my method, it is complicated. Please tomorrow have a look at my up-dated code and edit your demo to suit my code.

Comment: I have just updated my code, please review it. Everytime, the app starts, the `splash.cs` is launched and then the usercoin list is loaded with items

Comment: Let's say i want to check in the Listview where "France" is available. What is the code to do so ? How to make this code to work with custom listview: `for (int i = 0; i <= useritems.Count; i++)
        {
            listView.SetItemChecked(i, true);
        }` ?

Comment: If you can just  tell me how to have access on the `Checkbox cb` from outside of the listview.ItemClick` event ?

Comment: Hi, I have test my demo, can't reproduce your `when I first run the app, I am getting no items in my listview`. To be honest, I am disoriented from your comments. Ok, one question, one answer. Show your codes, say your question, I will find where is wrong, provide a solution.

Comment: I am following your demo step by step, I have no clue why I have no items in my listview. Now if you can just tell me how can I have access on the `Checkbox cb` from outside of the `listview.ItemClick` event and I ll solve the problem.

Comment: Yea right but I can't access it from outside of the listview.ItemClick event because `var ll = e.View as LinearLayout;` needs the `e` from the `listview event`

Comment: Maybe I have understood what do you mean, you can find `useritems`  and `daoList` from [here](https://github.com/xiaolvzi/ListViewCheckBox/blob/master/ListViewCheckBoxTest/MyApplication.cs), they are recording the `Checkbox`'s state.

Comment: That doesn't help, I need to access the checkbox from outside of the listview event so that I can use shared preference and assign the state of the checkbox on the start of the app. But i can't do it now since `var ll` need the `e` from the event.

Comment: Would you please give a look to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50859966/android-search-option-in-custom-listview-c-sharp)

Comment: I have edited my whole question. Please check it again.