# Android - Shared-preferences in Broadcast

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-intent, service

In my `BroadcastReceiver` class I am using `ISharedPreferences` to store a string coming from a service and compare it with the previous string (which is stored in my Preferences).

**BroadcastReceiver.cs**

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "TEST" })]
public class Receiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        ISharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        ISharedPreferencesEditor editor = pref.Edit();
        string old = pref.GetString("MYKEY", "nothing");
        Log.Error("lv", "OnReceive");
        string new = intent.GetStringExtra("alltotale");
        editor.PutString("MYKEY", new);
        editor.Commit();
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);
        builder.SetContentTitle("Old:" + old);
        builder.SetContentText("New" + new);
        builder.SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.Icon);
        Notification notif = builder.Build();
        NotificationManager notifmanager = context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;
        notifmanager.Notify(12, notif);
     }
 }
```

Now the weird thing is that the two strings (the old and the new) which are showing in the Notification are the same, although I am pretty sure that they are not. Which indicates that there are something wrong going on with the storage process. I don't know why it is giving the same string in the Notification, I don't see any problem with the Logic, so what is causing that to happen ?

Comment: Please add Xamarin tag.

Comment: @JoeLv-MSFT Okay done

Comment: @JoeLv-MSFT Would you please help me to find a solution here ?

Comment: `new` is key word, change it to other word, like `later`.

Comment: Hello, have you solved it?